# File handling in matlab using fgets and fprintf

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read data from one file and print it into another file.This is my code-

```
fileID=fopen('first3.txt','w');
fid=fopen('a.txt');
tline=fgets(fid);
tline=fgets(fid);
tline=fgets(fid);
tline=fgets(fid);
grp = textscan(tline,'%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s');

tline=fgets(fid);
n1=textscan(tline,'%.4f %.4f %.4f %c %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d');
fprintf(fileID,'   %f    %f    0.0000 %c   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n',double(n1{1}),...
                double(n1{2}),char(n1{4}),double(n1{5}),double(n1{6}),double(n1{7}),...
                double(n1{8}),double(n1{9}),double(n1{10}),double(n1{11}),double(n1{12}),...
                double(n1{13}),double(n1{13}),double(n1{15}),double(n1{16}));      

fclose(fileID);
fclose(fid);
```

This is my input file- `a.txt`

```
aaa
  bbb
ccc
  4  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ABC
    0.0000   -0.1976    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This is my output file-

```
   0.000000    -0.197600    0.0000 C   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0.000000    0.000000    0.0000  NUL   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0.000000    0.000000    0.0000  NUL   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0.000000    0.000000    0.0000  NUL   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0.000000    0.000000    0.0000  NUL   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why are these extra lines printed in the output file?

**Note-** I have to modify contents of some of the variables of the line before printing.That is why I am using `textscan` and `fget`.I cannot directly print the entire line as I have to modify some of the content.So,please suggest problems that are present in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're passing 15 values to `printf` in this line:

```
fprintf(fileID,'   %f    %f    0.0000 %c   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n',double(n1{1}),...
            double(n1{2}),char(n1{4}),double(n1{5}),double(n1{6}),double(n1{7}),...
            double(n1{8}),double(n1{9}),double(n1{10}),double(n1{11}),double(n1{12}),...
            double(n1{13}),double(n1{13}),double(n1{15}),double(n1{16}));
```

but the format string (`'   %f    %f    0.0000 %c   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n'`) only has 3 format parameters. If you have more inputs than parameters, MATLAB will repeat the line until it has used all of the inputs.

Either replace the `0` values in the format string with `%d`, or get rid of the superfluous inputs. E.g.:

```
fprintf(fileID,'   %f    %f    0.0000 %c   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n',double(n1{1}),...
            double(n1{2}),char(n1{4}));
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry how did I miss that.Thanks a lot.